# Serialization and observing changes in meteor collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, fabricjs

I have an application(ill make it short :p) - on the client side there is a list of objects, each of these objects has a property like "drawable" which is an fabricjs object instance to canvas. Point is, that I want to make it fully reactive and synchronized - each time someone moves an element on canvas or deletes an item from the list it has to be updated on every other client.

And here is the question - how to make and optimal data structure for such task, currently I am using something like this:

```
ListObject {
    name: 'name',
    otherAttributes: 'blahblah',
    drawable: 'fabricjsObjectInstance'
}
```

I dont want to make it serialize/deserialize way.

Some more examples of what I mean:

- when object on canvas is moved only its left and top attributes are changed - so I don't want to send and get whole canvas serialization
- it is possible to somehow bind an array object in code with minimongo collection?
- can I get rid of all 'Models' in js code and use only Meteor Collection with some behavior methods?

I am more than sure that I am doing it wrong or that I don't get meteor reactivnes. My point is not to get answer to every question, because it might be impossible, but to get some ideas or suggestions how to sort this mess out.

Comment: Unfortunately your whole approach to this seems to be wrong. Moving an element on a page can generate hundreds or thousands of events in mere seconds. Even with massive throttling, it will still be a huge load on your DB. To still achieve it, you could simply store the positions in the DB (`posX` and `posY` for example) and use methods to update the positions, delete or add elements, and also store additional data to rebuild your objects client-side. If you want to do it without Mongo (which I recommend), you can start by [reading this](https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-meteor-streams.html).

Comment: Ok, so making fabric completely "live" is wrong - I would make some timeouts anyway probably, currenlty its not a problem either.

Comment: Lets skip part with observing object movement and transformations. Biggest issue currenlty is my way of looking on meteor reactivnes. I have an object called ex. "Obj", it has properties, constructor and so on. Then I have to serialize it, insert into collection - > get changes on other client - > detect type of serialized object, deserialize data into newly created object(I know, its a short version of what would have to be realy implemented) aaaaaaaaand I am wondering can I skip this part and make it just "observing" a property.